# Ext.device.connection Overriding (Adding Global Listerners)

Tags: sencha-touch-2

Is Ext.device.connection in sencha touch 2 can be overridden by some custom code like below. 
Basically here we are trying to check for internet connection at application level and redirect the user to common page

```
 Ext.define('SLS.BRND.WEB.common.CustomConnection', {
    override :  'Ext.device.connection',

    constructor : function() {
        var me = this;

        me.callParent(arguments);

        me.on('exception', 'checkSessionTimeout', me);
    },

    checkSessionTimeout : function() {
        alert('this');
    }
});
```

Comment: hey, what is the question? does your snippet works or not?

Answer (score 0):

Your override should be `override :  'Ext.device.Connection',` but I'm not quite sure this will work, depending when the Connection class singleton gets instantiated and your override is registered. In other words, does registering for the override cause the ST singleton to be instantiated, or does ST itself use the Connection class before you're able to override it. You're most likely bet would be to mixin the new method, or, since ST classes are open, just do `Ext.device.Connection.checkSessionTimeout = function () { alert('this'); };`